# Laravel 4. Saving image with Dropzone to Database.

Tags: laravel, upload, dropzone.js

Hi I have problem with upload images to databases and folders.
I have dropzone and intervention image

Want to load images thrown by the user to the database. It will be a few pictures, not one.

Database connection I have everything done, because on one image without dropzone worked.

Problems:
**Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object**

my controller

```
 $image = Input::hasFile('image');
            $destinationPath = 'uploads';
            $filename = str_random(12);
            // $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $path = public_path('img/offers/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->
            resize(null, 600, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
                })
            ->insert('img/watermark.png', 'bottom-left', 10, 10)
            ->save($path);
```

my view:

```
            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/create', 'method' => 'POST','class'=>'dropzone', 'file'=>true)) }}

    <p>
      {{ Form::label('Title:') }}
      {{ Form:: text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('image', Select images') }}
        {{ Form::file('image', array('multiple')) }}
    </p>




    {{ Form::submit('Create offers', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently have an system which is using DropZone to upload files via Ajax.
The following is the code I use to process the images. You can see that rather than passing the path to the file, I simply pass the file object to Image::make and allow it to find the file. You can of course pass it the file path instead.

```
$file = Input::file('post_photo');
var_dump($file); // lets make sure we have what we expect
var_dump($file->getRealPath()); // this does output the path within tmp, IE /tmp/phpSuJC2h
$image           = Image::make($file);
$image_1           = Image::make($file->getRealPath()); // this also works
// Do manipulation
```

As the error you are getting implies that Input::file is not returning an object as it should, I would begin by doing a var_dump on $image. That should output an object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile ; If it does not, that should at least get you started in regards to finding the error.

When debugging Ajax uploads, I often find it useful to use the development tools in Chrome (or whichever browser you prefer), to inspect the request payload being sent to the server.  For example:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary6cBHjCmPgfALq9aM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post_photo"; filename="DSC_0088.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary6cBHjCmPgfALq9aM--
```

Answer (score 0):

`$image = Input::hasFile('image');` just returns a boolean indicating whether the input params have a file named `image`. It does not return an actual Input object you can use.

To do that you need to call the `file` method on `Input`:

```
$image = Input::file('image');
```

Comment: Still the same message; /

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the content file on the database you can use:

```
$image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( File::get($data['image']) );

DB::table('foo')->where('id', $id)->update( [ 'image'=> $image ] );
```

When you read the file from the DB, you just have to use the **image** field in the src attribute of the img html tag.